# RAM-disk vs Boost interprocess communication

Tags: c++, boost, interprocess, boost-interprocess, ramdisk

To let a set of processes communicate, what are the advantages and disadvantages between:

1. RAM-disk
2. Boost interprocess communication

A RAM-disk allows to communicate with programs that only use files.

How big is the performance penalty of a RAM-disk due to the file system interface to be replicated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a false dichotomy.

If you're sharing via

- files on RAM-disk - you're still using memory-mapped files (implemented Boost Interprocess)
- named pipes (FIFO's on a unix) you're still using IPC (because pipes or socketpairs are IPC primitives).

You can't /avoid/ IPC by using a RAM disk.

In fact, it sends alarm signals because it sounds like you're assuming it will somehow be "simpler" using a RAM disk. In practice, it's only simpler if you don't do proper locking. This is just a source of bugs, though.

Comment: AFAIK, a RAM-disk is seen by the OS like a normal disk. So if I want to send, e.g., a log to a log viewer, I can do it through the RAM-disk in a transparent manner, i.e. doing exactly the same operations needed to manage files; here the RAM is the disk. Memory mapping, on the other hand, is a copy of part of a disk in RAM, so if I modify something in the RAM portion, the same change will be applied (later?) to the disk.

Comment: What's your point? Is your point that you're not actually doing IPC, but just sharing files?

Comment: IPC requires to use specific functions which are radically different from the ones provided by, e.g., fstream.

Comment: My point is that I want to move data from one executable to another, and I have to decide whether to keep the current file based approach on a RAM disk, or to move to an IPC (pipes, ...) approach. This change must bring good performance improvements to be taken.

Comment: It all depends on the usage patterns. If you're transferring large amounts of data in streaming mode, then going IPC will likely be faster. If you're sending many updates then pipes or even udp might be faster. If it's just some document exchange (small documents, less than 100 p/min) a RAM disk may be a very good quick win

Comment: I would be interested in the quantitative aspects of what you just wrote. Do you have any references/links about it? Thank you!

Comment: Just my experience. It makes a bit of sense though. Sharing files precludes streaming and as such is necessarily less efficient than streaming for large files. I have no quantitatives. Even if I did, they wouldn't be relevant to your particular development cost/performance trade-off

Answer (score 0):

If you want to know the performance penalty, I think you could do some tests because I do not think your solution is common.

Anyway, if you want two processes to get communicated using some type of interprocess communication infrastructure, use the provided by boost, because it is designed to do what you want to do, it does not requires extra infrastructure and it is actually too portable across platforms.